# Automate backup and deletion of Microsoft sql database using python

Tags: python, sql-server

So what I need to do is to backup my Microsoft Sql database and delete 6 month old data from the DB. Both of these processes must be automated. Right now I am stuck at the backup. I have been studying different things and tried to apply them, but most of the help that I have found is regarding database systems other than that of microsoft sql.

for instance I have found the following code

```
for db_name in db_names:
try:
    file_path = ''
    dumper = " -U %s --password -Z 9 -f %s -F c %s  "
   os.putenv('PGPASSWORD', db_password)
    bkp_file = '%s_%s.sql' % (db_name, time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S'))
    glob_list = glob.glob(dump_dir + db_name + '*' + '.pgdump')
    file_path = os.path.join(dump_dir, bkp_file)
    command = 'pg_dump' + dumper % (db_username, file_path, db_name)
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    subprocess.call('gzip ' + file_path, shell=True)
except:
    print("Couldn't backup database" % (db_name))
```

The above code gives me the following errors

```
'sqldumper' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
'gzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

I think this is happening because this  method is for postgres sql data.

Any guideline or tutorial or help of any other sort is highly appreciated.

Comment: `gzip` and `sqldumper` are not available on Windows by default. It looks like you recycled some code for UNIX like machines.

Comment: Would you know any work around for this? @KlausD.

Comment: That code is for Postgres, not SQL Server, so not sure why you though it would work. Why don't you just use SQL Server Agent to setup an automated backup job? You can do it directly from SSMS

Comment: I understand that it is for Postgres as I mentioned this in the question as well, I  thought like pg_dump there could be a method for mssql dump.  
And I didn't think about SQL Agent method. Can you please guide about that.?

Comment: You can use the Maintenance Plan wizard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/use-the-maintenance-plan-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL you can adapt your code for this command:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [demodb] TO DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/data/demodb.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = 'demodb-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10"
```

More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to know, how you are running the python script.
those errors you are getting, likely from windows command prompt.
Make sure you are importing the gzip module in your python code above.
Here's one example for MySQL:
[Python Script for MySQL Database Backup][1]
[1]: https://tecadmin.net/python-script-for-mysql-database-backup/

later on, for automating the script if you are using Linux, you can use cron job to run it anytime you want.
For windows you can use Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Hi. I am running this script on VS code using windows 10. I have gzip imported in my code too.

Comment: Instead of VS-code could you try the same using normal windows command prompt.
First try to run python on windows cmd.
Then once python prompt opens up try to import those modules.
eg: import gzip also import that dumper which you using for your code.
if they import successfully then after exiting try to run your python script in widows cmd.
eg: python3 backup.py